# What does START_STICKY exactly do?

Tags: android

I'm a bit confused about this. If I have a service and I make a thread inside the service to do a background job, in case of memory limits, if system kills the service, does it kill the service AND the thread created inside or only the serivce (I know the service itself runs on UI thread) and does this "START_STICKY" cause to restart the service AND the thread or just the service. If only the service restarts with the thread previously killed there's no thread to continue my background job. and if system restarts the service by calling onCreate() then another thread would be created and this is really something I don't want. Because I make a schedule with AlarmManager in the first thread (killing thread doesn't change AlarmManager sechedule) and I don't want the new thread to make another schedule with AlarmManager.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onSaveInstanceState()` to save your thread's state when the service is destroyed, and when the service is restarted the `savedInstance` passed to your service's `onCreate()` will not be null and will have the state you saved, in that case you  shouldn't re-schedule your alarm and you should continue where you left off.